# Upload a photo from camera or gallery in android

Tags: java, android, permissions

Having the following error:
android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/temp.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()

when I choose Option Camera from chosen AlertDialog

And the following error when I try to choose a photo from Gallery:
BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0 (Is a directory)
The Gallery opens up, but I can't choose an image to set it to my ImageView
Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button contactsButton, galleryButton;

public static final int Gallery_Code = 100;
public static final int Contacts_Code = 101;


private ImageView imageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    contactsButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonContacts);
    galleryButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonGallery);
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    contactsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Contacts_Code);

        }
    });

    galleryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            uploadImage();


        }
    });
}

private void uploadImage() {
    final String[] options = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery", "Cancel"};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Upload Photo");
    builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (options[item].equals("Take Photo")) {

                Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                takePicture.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);

            } else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery")) {
                Intent gallery = new Intent();
                gallery.setType("image/*");
                gallery.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(gallery, "Select Picture"), 1);
            } else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {


            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
            File[] files = f.listFiles();
            if (files != null) {
                for (File temp : files) {
                    if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                        f = temp;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap;
                BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                        bitmapOptions);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                String path = android.os.Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator
                        + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                f.delete();
                OutputStream outFile = null;
                File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                try {
                    outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                    outFile.flush();
                    outFile.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == 2) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
            String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
            c.close();
            Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            imageView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        }
    }
}


private void checkPermission(String readContacts, int contacts_code) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, readContacts)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

        // Requesting the permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{readContacts},
                contacts_code);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "Permission already granted",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        if (contacts_code == Contacts_Code) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ContactsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super
            .onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,
                    permissions,
                    grantResults);

    if (requestCode == Gallery_Code) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Gallery Permission Granted",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            Intent gallery = new Intent();
            gallery.setType("image/*");
            gallery.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(gallery, "Select Picture"), 1);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Gallery Permission Denied",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    } else if (requestCode == Contacts_Code) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Contacts Permission Granted",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ContactsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Contacts Permission Denied",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
} }
```

Comment: Please, use a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `FileUriExposedException`. Did you google for it? No. Use a FileProvider is the solution.

Comment: Thank you! I looked through FileProvider, now the camera app opens, but the image is not displayed in ImageView after the photo is taken, the same about gallery,  photo does not get displayed in an ImageView

Comment: BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0 (Is a directory)  The error message I am getting